# How to use existing docker-compose.yml file in AWS Elastic Container Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I have multi container application and using `docker-compose.yml` file to start the application. I'm planning to use AWS Elastic Container Service for deployment. From the tutorials, I came across to create a container definitions in task definitions instead of using user defined compose file in AWS ECS console.

How to use existing docker-compose.yml file in AWS Elastic Container Service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does seem that there is support to use the ECS CLI to use a `docker-compose` file using the [ecs-cli-compose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose.html) command.

This will translate your `docker-compose` file and create a task definition that is able to be used with ECS

The [task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html) in ECS is a mapping file for all container based configuration. Within this file you can define the container definitions for each container within the task, define port mappings, any custom commands, volume mounting etc.

Comment: Can we use AWS CodeDeploy for user-defined `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: There appears to be a cli command you can use added it to the answer